# how to run progress bar until the background plying audio stoped

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, audio-player, swift4.2

i'm working on a audio player  where i have to allow the audio to play in background, i have done with audio sessions but i stuck in progress bar when i play audio in background and again open my app the progress bar and timer stoped, i need to run them also in background. i mean progress bar should be updated with timer if i move to other views or minimise the app.

```
 @IBAction func btnPlayMusicAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    if isPlaying == false {
        self.btnPlayMusicPro.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PauseIcon"), for: .normal)
        self.isPlaying = true
        self.audioPlayer?.play()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1.0, target: self,selector: (#selector(updateRemainingTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats:true)



    }else{
        self.btnPlayMusicPro.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlayIcon"), for: .normal)
        self.isPlaying = false
        if (audioPlayer?.isPlaying)!{
            self.audioPlayer?.pause()
        }
        self.timer?.invalidate()



    }
}
```

her is the method updateRemainingTime()

```
    @objc func updateRemainingTime(){
    let currentTime =   Int((audioPlayer?.currentTime)!)
    let duration = Int((audioPlayer?.duration)!)
    let seconds = currentTime % 60
    let minutes = (currentTime / 60) % 60
    let hours = (currentTime / 3600)

    var remainingTime:String = ""
    if currentTime >= 3600{
        remainingTime = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }else{
        remainingTime = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }

    self.lblPlayMusicTimePro.text = remainingTime
    Tray.remainingAudioTime = remainingTime

    if currentTime  == duration-1{
        timer?.invalidate()

        if (audioPlayer?.isPlaying)!{
            self.audioPlayer?.currentTime = 0
            self.audioPlayer?.stop()
        }
        self.btnPlayMusicPro.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlayIcon"), for: .normal)
        self.isPlaying = false
        self.musicProgressViewPro.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
        self.lblPlayMusicTimePro.text = "00:00"
        self.lblMusicTimePro.text = "00:00"
    }else {
        let currentProgress = Float((audioPlayer?.currentTime)! / (audioPlayer?.duration)!)
        Tray.progressTime = currentProgress
        self.musicProgressViewPro.setProgress(currentProgress, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: When you either come back from an inactive state or from another view you need to build in a call to refresh musicProgressViewPro.  You can do that through your app delegate for coming from an inactive state or through notifications (calling a remote function on a global variable or object).

Comment: Your timer won't execute in the background, but it should resume once your app returns to the foreground.

Comment: how i can refresh the time in appDelegate?